# How to get result like this in sql using date diff

Tags: sql

```
ColA           ColB            RESULTCol
A      |    2/12/2014     |      0
A      |    2/13/2014     |      1      
A      |    2/14/2014     |      1
B      |    2/11/2014     |      0
B      |    2/16/2014     |      5
B      |    2/17/2014     |      1
C      |    2/19/2014     |      0
C      |    2/20/2014     |      1
C      |    2/22/2014     |      2
C      |    2/25/2014     |      3
```

How do I get ResultCol from ColA and ColB with date diff function?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  What exactly are you trying to get in the `RESULTCol`?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried already.

Comment: So which DBMS are you using?

Comment: This is not the complete question, how can datediff two column untill both have dates? and you have colA as text column?

Comment: I am trying to get date difference between two row based on the value at the ColA. I am using sql server for it. First value always starts from 0 and second value will be current date value and previous row date value but it depends on the value of colA.  Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: @Piyush : I am using sql server

Comment: see posted answer.. @Joe

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `lag()` function.  That seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

```
select IDCode, DateValue,
       coalesce(datediff(day, lag(DateValue) over (partition by IDCode order by DateValue),
                         DateValue),
                0)
from taable t;
```

I'm not sure which database you are using; this uses `datediff()`, the SQL Server function.  (Other databases have similar functions.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with a `CTE`:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By ColA Order By ColB Asc) Row
    From    YourTable
)
Select      A.ColA, A.ColB, Coalesce(DateDiff(Day, B.ColB, A.ColB), 0) ResultCol
From        Cte A
Left Join   Cte B   On  A.ColA = B.ColA
                    And A.Row = B.Row + 1
Order By A.ColA Asc, A.ColB Asc
```